# Why does `defer recover()` not catch panics?

Tags: go, deferred-execution

Why does a call to `defer func() { recover() }()` successfully recover a panicking goroutine, but a call to `defer recover()` not?

As an minimalistic example, this code doesn't panic

```
package main

func main() {
    defer func() { recover() }()
    panic("panic")
}
```

However, replacing the anonymous function with recover directly panics

```
package main

func main() {
    defer recover()
    panic("panic")
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Handling panic](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics) section mentions that

> Two built-in functions, `panic` and `recover`, assist in reporting and handling run-time panics
>
> The `recover` function allows a program to manage behavior of a panicking goroutine.
>
> Suppose a function `G` **defers a function `D`** that calls `recover` and a `panic` occurs in a function on the same goroutine in which `G` is executing.
>
> When the running of deferred functions reaches `D`, the return value of `D`'s call to `recover` will be the value passed to the call of panic.
>   If D returns normally, without starting a new panic, the panicking sequence stops.

That illustrates that `recover` is meant to be called in a deferred function, not directly.
When it panic, the "deferred function" cannot be the built-in `recover()` one, but one specified in a **[defer statement](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements)**.

```
DeferStmt = "defer" Expression .
```

> The expression must be a function or method call; it cannot be parenthesized.
>   **Calls of built-in functions are restricted as for [expression statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Expression_statements)**.
>
> **With the exception of specific built-in functions**, function and method calls and receive operations can appear in statement context.

Answer (score 16):

Quoting from the documentation of the built-in function [`recover()`](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#recover):

> If recover is called **outside** the deferred function it will **not** stop a panicking sequence.

In your second case `recover()` itself is the deferred function, and obviously  `recover()` does not call itself. So this will not stop the panicking sequence.

If `recover()` would call `recover()` in itself, it would stop the panicking sequence (but why would it do that?).

**Another Interesting Example:**

The following code also doesn't panic (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/1_aFKorkTZ)):

```
package main

func main() {
    var recover = func() { recover() }
    defer recover()
    panic("panic")
}
```

What happens here is we create a `recover` variable of function type which has a value of an anonymous function calling the built-in `recover()` function. And we specify calling the value of the `recover` variable to be the deferred function, so calling the builtin `recover()` from that stops the panicing sequence.

Comment: And why they specified `recover()` that way: maybe it'd be additional implementation work to allow bare `defer recover()`, and more importantly, silently swallowing all `panic`s is risky in the way ignoring `err` is: it makes it much easier to have a problem that stops your program from doing what you want and not know what it is.

Comment: @twotwotwo In one of my applications, I'm writing to a channel, and I don't want to panic if it's closed. Hence `defer recover()`. The entire routine is basically `defer recover(); ch1 <- <- ch2`.

Comment: @EthanReesor; noted, but usually the rule is that "[Only the sole/final sender (or some delegate thereof) should ever close a channel](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/RmfHSHE9e30)" (so no sending after the close). Some things achieve this by signalling shutdown some other way (like closing a `quit` or `cancel` channel on one end, then checking quit status with a `select { case <-quit: /* ...do shutdown stuff... */ default: }` on the other). More narrowly, I can't change the spec; if you want to catch 'em all `defer func() { recover() }` is the only way.

Comment: @EthanReesor Graceful shutdown of parallel stuff really deserves more attention than I can give it now or fits in a comment; what you want to do, and how you do it (closing a channel, `close(quit)`, `sync.WaitGroup`, etc), sometimes need some thought specific to your situation.

Comment: @twotwotwo Do you have a reading recommendation for learning good parallel/asynchronous practices for a language like Go? Which is to say, a language that has co/goroutines and channels, not threads.

Comment: [Here are some links and vague statements.](https://gist.github.com/twotwotwo/fe5c5020a2bb5f7f0ce3) Not like you have to read all that to make progress, but lots of things to snack on over time. If you have a particular scenario you think might be possible to improve on, SO may be able to help with some info on what you've done and the problem you're solving (not a promise that I have the time, or that any of us will necessarily improve on your approach!).

Comment: is it possible to recover a panic coming from main, deferring the recover function in a test case? Docs samples don't work

Answer (score 2):

An observation is that the real problem here is the design of `defer` and thus the answer should say that.

Motivating this answer, `defer` currently needs to take exactly one level of nested stack from a lambda, and the runtime uses a particular side effect of this constraint to make a determination on whether `recover()` returns nil or not.

Here's an example of this:

```
func b() {
  defer func() { if recover() != nil { fmt.Printf("bad") } }()
}

func a() {
  defer func() {
    b()
    if recover() != nil {
      fmt.Printf("good")
    }
  }()
  panic("error")
}
```

The `recover()` in `b()` should return nil.

In my opinion, a better choice would have been to say that `defer` takes a function BODY, or block scope (rather than a function call,) as its argument. At that point, `panic` and the `recover()` return value could be tied to a particular stack frame, and any inner stack frame would have a `nil` pancing context. Thus, it would look like this:

```
func b() {
  defer { if recover() != nil { fmt.Printf("bad") } }
}

func a() {
  defer {
    b()
    if recover() != nil {
      fmt.Printf("good")
    }
  }
  panic("error")
}
```

At this point, it's obvious that `a()` is in a panicking state, but `b()` is not, and any side effects like "being in the first stack frame of a deferred lambda" aren't necessary to correctly implement the runtime.

So, going against the grain here: The reason this doesn't work as might be expected, is a mistake in the design of the `defer` keyword in the go language, that was worked around using non-obvious implementation detail side effects and then codified as such.