# Why this program prints 421 in result?

Tags: go, panic, defer-keyword

I can't to understand, why this program prints `421` instead of `431`?

```
package main

import "fmt"

var x int
func f() int {
    x++
    return x
}

func main() {
    o := fmt.Println

    defer o(f())
    defer func() {
        defer o(recover())
        o(f())
    }()

    defer f()
    defer recover()

    panic(f())
}
```

Below I added the comment how I guess:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var x int
func f() int {
    x++
    return x
}

func main() {
    o := fmt.Println

    defer o(f()) // x=1
    defer func() {
        defer o(recover()) // x=3 from panic (but if we ll execute this program we ll see 2)
        o(f()) // x=4
    }()

    defer f() // x=2
    defer recover() //nil

    panic(f()) // x=3
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`defer`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements) does **not** call the function, but it **does evaluate** its arguments "immediately". Also a call to `recover()` only stops the panicing state if it gets called from a deferred function (`defer recover()` does not qualify for this). See [Why does `defer recover()` not catch panics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518109/why-does-defer-recover-not-catch-panics/29518404#29518404)

In the light of this: Let's number the lines:

```
L1: o := fmt.Println

L2: defer o(f()) // x = 1

L3: defer func() {
L4:     defer o(recover()) // recover() returns 2
L5:     o(f())             // x = 4, it gets printed
L6: }()

L7: defer f() // after panic: x = 3
L8: defer recover()

L9: panic(f()) // x = 2
```

**The execution of the above code will go like this:**

L2: evaulates the params of `o()`, `f()` is called, `x` is incremented to `1` (this will be printed later). `o()` is not yet called.

L3: Deferred function is not called yet, skip its whole body for now.

L7: `f()` is not called yet, `x` remains `1`.

L8: `recover()` is not called.

L9: `f()` is called, increments `x` to `2`, and returns it, so `2` is passed to `panic()`.

We're in a panicking state, so deferred functions are executed now (in LIFO order).

L8: `recover()` is called but does not stop the panicing state.

L7: `f()` is called now, increments `x` to `3`.

L3: This anonymous function is now executed.

L4: `recover()` returns `2` (the value that was passed to `panic()`), this will be printed later, but not yet, as call to `o()` is deferred. Panicing state stops here.

L5: `f()` is called, increments `x` to `4`, it gets printed right away.

L4: deferred function `o()` is now executed, printing the above value `2`.

L2: deferred function `o()` is now executed, printing the previously evaluated value `1`.

End of program.